# Display real time scale on xAxis

Tags: highcharts

A have this code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1cg3fn?file=index.js to plot a serie data based on time.

[image]

At the moment, on xAxis, the distance of `1. Mar` and `7. Mar`, of `7. Mar` and `8. Mar`, of `8. Mar` and `10. Mar`, etc. is the same.

I'm wondering if there is any setting in highcharts to display these time points based on real time scale. In other words, we still leave the place for `2. Mar`, `3. Mar` which don't have y values.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an enabled `ordinal` option in Highstock, you can disable it:

```
xAxis: {
    ordinal: false
},
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rh2q2u?file=index.js

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal